# Integration of a 1-form

Tags: differential-forms, bilinear-form, line-integrals

I have to calculate the integral $\int_{\gamma}d\omega$
$$\omega=(y+z)dx+(z+x) dy+(x-y) dz$$
$\gamma$ is the intersection between the sferic surface $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and che plane $y=z$

I want to solve it computing $d\omega$ directly with wedge products, so I found $d\omega=-2dy\wedge dz$. Now I establish a parametrization for $\gamma$ which is $$\begin{cases}
x=cost\\
y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sint\\
z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}sint
\end{cases} $$
Where $t\in[0,2\pi]$, so I have to evaluate this integral:
$$\int_{[0,2\pi]} -2dy\wedge dz(-sint, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cost, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cost) $$

But I don't know how to evaluate that, usually I use this method when integrating a 2-form on a 2-surface. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to apply Stokes theorem

$$ \int _{\gamma} \omega = \int_{D} d\omega,$$

where $D$ is a surface with $\partial D = \gamma$. You need to find this $D$ first.

There are lots of them, the simplest one is the intersection of the plane $y=z$ with the unit ball. It has a parametrization

\begin{cases}
x= r \cos t\\
y=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t\\
z=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t
\end{cases}

with $0<r<1$ and $ 0<t<2\pi$.

Or you can just use your parametrization of $\gamma$ and integrate $\omega$.

Comment: But now have I to integrate $\omega$ and not $d\omega$?

Comment: ah yes, $\int_\gamma d\omega$ does not quite make sense.

Comment: Ah ok! So I integrate $d\omega$ on the circle. Now everything makes sense, thanks a lot!